# Change visibilty in child class

Tags: typescript

It appears that it is possible to change property visibility in child class from `protected` to `public`:

```
class BaseFoo  {
    protected foo;
}

class Foo extends BaseFoo {
   foo = 1;
}

new Foo().foo;
```

But not in any other possible combination. I believe that accidental change to `public` by omitting visibility modifier is more harmful than changing from `protected` to `private` (which isn't allowed).

What is the explanation for that? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the question has been discussed, and then closed as "working as intended", in the repo [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9677). OOP theory is a bit beyond my expertise, but my understanding of the maintainer's logic is that protected is the category of methods that should be private on the base class, but are *allowed* to be public on children. Then

```
class Foo extends BaseFoo {
   protected foo = 1;
}
```

is the way to keep `foo` "private" on `Foo`. As to the question of implicit property types (should `foo = 1` default to `public`?), that seems to make sense as the expected behavior. Defaulting to public is the standard throughout TS, and if you want to make that not possible, you'd use:

```
class BaseFoo  {
    private foo;
}

class Foo extends BaseFoo {
   foo = 1; // compiler error
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not sure that the issue you linked is related. The issue in question is that `protected`->`public` works, but `protected`->`private`  and `public`->`protected` don't.

Comment: @estus Excellent point - I linked to the wrong issue. Oops. I had multiple TS-related tabs open. The [original link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3402) you saw is only about overrides generally. The [correct link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9677) (now updated in my answer) discussed the protected->private question, and I think is relevant here.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked the points that the team made and still not sure if it's expected. No, implicit type isn't a problem, it's just too easy to accidentally break encapsulation, and still unclear what's the logic behind the fact that protected->public works but public->protected doesn't. I guess that the issue needs to be opened for that.